# How to create recyclerview witch 3 columns (Kotlin)

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Help me create recyclerview with 3 colums, like a show picture below[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/somgt.png)

Answer (score 1):

Simply use span count with Grid layout manager, here is example

In XML:

```
app:spanCount="3"
app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager"
```

in JAVA:

```
recView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this,3,RecyclerView.VERTICAL,false));
```

in KOTLIN:

```
recView.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(this,3,RecyclerView.VERTICAL,false)
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(mContext, 3));
//GridLayoutManager(context, nºcolumns)
recyclerView.setAdapter(yourAdapter);
```

Comment: Hey, @fsets. You should probably add an explanation for why this is a solution